# If $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 > 0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 =2$ , then $P = (x_1 + x_2) (x_3 + x_4)$ is bounded between?

Tags: functions, bounded-variation

If $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 > 0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 =2$, then $P = (x_1 + x_2) (x_3 + x_4)$ is bounded between,

A. 0 and 1

B. 1 and 2

C. 2 and 3

D. 3 and 4

How do you solve these kinds of questions? I usually put many values and check the results like putting all = 0.5 gives $P = 1$ etc but how to actually solve these questions in a general way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Remark that your problem is equivalent to : let $x,y>0$ such that $x+y=2$, then $xy$ is between ...

- By taking $x\rightarrow 0$ and $y\rightarrow 2$ for example, you can see that the lower bound of $xy$ is $0$.
- For the upper bound, you have in general $xy\leq \frac{(x+y)^2}{4}$, so that $xy\leq 1$. Remark that this upper bound is achieved for $x=y=1$.